# Is it possible to delete files in SWARM?

Tags: storage, ipfs, swarm, storj

If not what are some similar protocols to IPFS and SWARM that allow you to delete files?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot delete files in Swarm. This is one of the pillars of this distributed technology; once the data up there is no way to take it down.

That being said; Swarm is an opportunistic framework; nodes will get paid for serving content, and will tend to keep content they can make more money of. Popular content will be requested more, and since storage space ultimately is finite, less popular content will be lost over time.

There is an insurance scheme in development, called [Swap, Swear and Swindle (or sw^3)](https://youtu.be/9Cgyhsjsfbg?list=PLaM7G4Llrb7xNkX0gugDyUm6Z_RrCvWPk) that will let you pay the network specifically for storing content regardless of popularity (compensating their potential loss of storing that content instead of more profitable content).